# Convex set global minimum

Tags: real-analysis

I have some troubles to understand how to prove the following:

Assume $g(x,y)$ is convex, but not differentiable on $D:\{(x,y) \mid \sqrt {x^2+y^2}\le 1\}$. Also assume $g(x,y)$ > $g(0,0)$ for all $(x,y)$  $\in$ $U_{1/4} (0,0)$. Show that $g$ has a global minimum in $(0,0)$.

In my book there was no definition given on this kind problem. Now i cannot picture this problem in terms of geometry. I know i can make a open ball but i dont know how it relates to $f$ and how we can interpret it geometrically. Besides that how should i tackle the problem, the answer model shows that make $t$ small enough. They use the definition of the line segment with $0\le t\le 1$. But how can that $t$ relate to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Assume that $g(x,y)<g(0,0)$ for some $(x,y)\in D$, and try to get a contradiction by considering the line segment with end points $(0,0)$ and $(x,y)$. Further hint: Some points on this line segment lie in $U_{1/4}(0,0)$.

**Edit:** Now that you had some time to work on my hints, here is a solution the way I would write it. (Warning: My writing style is often rater terse, leaving the reader to fill in some detail.) But first, a small thing to clear up: You never *defined* $U_{1/4}(0,0)$, but I take it to be a ball – closed or open, doesn't really matter – of radius $1/4$ and centered at the origin. Perhaps excluding the origin itself? If not, you neglected to excempt the case $(x,y)=(0,0)$ from the inequality $g(x,y)>g(0,0)$.

All right; assume now, for contradiction, that $(x,y)\in D$ satisfies $g(x,y)\le g(0,0)$. (I am in fact proving that there is no other global minimum here. Replace by a sharp inequality if you wish.) Pick a suitable $t$ with $0<t<\frac14$. For example, $t=\frac18$ will do. Note that $(0,0)\ne(tx,ty)\in U_{1/4}(0,0)$. Write this instead as a convex combination $(tx,ty)=t(x,y)+(1-t)(0,0)$, so that we can apply the definition of convexity:
$$ g(tx,ty)\le tg(x,y)+(1-t)g(0,0) .$$
Recall our assumption $g(x,y)\le g(0,0)$, and insert in the above, to get
$$ g(tx,ty)\le tg(0,0)+(1-t)g(0,0)=g(0,0) .$$
But since $(tx,ty)\in U_{1/4}(0,0)$, the opposite inequality is assumed to hold, i.e., $g(tx,ty)>g(0,0)$. And that is the contradiction we're after, so we're done.

Comment: How can you get a contradiction on the line segment? What kind of contradiction should i be looking for?

Comment: Think about the definition of convexity. It is an inequality, right? Look for the opposite inequality. As a warmup exercise, do the one-dimensional analogue: Say $f$ is a real function on $[0,1]$ with $f(t)>f(0)$ when $0<t<\ frac14$, and assume $f(1)<f(0)$. Do you see what's wrong with that? If not, draw a picture!

Comment: Can you give a concrete one variable function so i can graph i am trying but wont get it

Comment: Is $f(1)>f(0)$ than if we assume the opposite then we will have a contradiction

Comment: I got that, but now i know that if we draw a convex function we know that the line segment must be above the graph. So now i get that also, and know how can i get the line segment below the graph if i assume $g(0,0) > g(x,y)$. Which definition exists out there to prove global minimum when function is not differentiable? Please tell me!!

Comment: I have never heard of a definition of global minimum that requires differentiability!? If $f\colon X\to\mathbb{R}$ is a function, then $x_0\in X$ is a global minimum if $f(x_0)\le f(x)$ for every $x\in X$. Here, $X$ can be any sort of set, for many of which the question of differentiability doesn't even make any sense.

Comment: Ok i see now. But now i  do not know how to apply this contradiction to prove my question above. A step by step working of the problem would help